# что лучше использовать для websocket на android?

Tags: java, android, websocket

Здравствуйте! Начал изучать android и столкнулся с подключением websocket.
В интернете поискал, много неконкретных и старых тем. В частности упоминаются:

`nv-websocket-client`
`Autobahn android`
`socketConnections` - самый свежий из трех.
Что можете подсказать?

Сокеты нужны для онлайн чата. Сервер пишу на python/django с использованием channels.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас лучше использовать okhht3 для работы в socket. Это самое удобное на мой взгляд решение. При этом у вас помимо веб сокетов и стандартный http клиент есть.